# Instagram API returning Error "InstagramAPI\ConfigureResponse Uploaded image isn't in the right format"

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am trying to post some images on Instagram using Insta API but sometimes it gets failed, my application is in php. Below is the description of the error which I received in the Error Log.

In case of failure,

```
InstagramAPI\ConfigureResponse Object
(
    [upload_id] => 
    [media_id] => 
    [image_url] => 
    [media_code] => 
    [status] => fail
    [message] => Uploaded image isn't in the right format
    [fullResponse] => 
)
```

In case of success,

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [id] => 13793xxxxx1912041_385xxxx61
    [code] => BMkxxxxGD-xx
)
```

I am not sure, why I am getting this error sometimes, I tried using jpg format images as well.

Please help !!
Thanks